# How popular is ‘Contrafibularities’ as a day-to-day English word?

Tags: word-choice, is-it-a-word

I found the phrase “My sincerest contrafibularities, Tim” given to one of the comments to [my question about the word, 'Cromulent'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49251/how-popular-is-the-word-cromulent-if-i-use-this-word-in-conversation-with-nat) in EL&U site.

As I was totally unfamiliar with the word, ‘contrafibularities’ (as well as 'Cromulent'), I checked Cambridge, Oxford, and Merriam-Webster online dictionary. None of them registers ‘Contrafibularities.’ GoogleNgram doesn’t carry this word either.

However, I was able to find the definition of this word as ‘A form of congratulations as used by Edmund Blackadder to mock Doctor Samuel Johnson, author of the dictionary’ in www.urbandictionary.com, and its origin;

Blackadder: "Allow me to be the first to offer Dr. Johnson my most sincere contrafibularities! I am anaspeptic ... Contrafibularities: Obviously from contra, against, + fibula, the smaller of the two bones in the lower leg. Means 'pulling one's leg,' in www.reviewers-choice.com.

I don’t understand why combination of prefix ‘contra’ and ‘fibula’ come to form the meaning of ‘Congratulations.’

But as it looks like the salute giver used this word quite casually (I think) to congratulate a comment poster, the word (contrafibularities) wouldn’t be any unusual word.

However, I would like to make sure of popularity and usability of this word. The word may be taken for granted as casually among native English speakers even among cab-drivers and burger-shop waitresses (I use these jobs just for the purpose of reffering to an average person).

But, if I speak this word in conversation with or use in writing to native speakers, am I ridiculed or jeered by them as being awkward?

Comment: Quoth Blackadder, addressing Yoichi: “I am anaspeptic, frasmotic, even compunctuous that my contrafibulations have caused you such pericombobulation.”  In other words, he’s indeed *pulling your leg*.  See [here](http://www.reviewers-choice.com/blackadder_the_third.htm).

Comment: I would say this word may safely be avoided. Do not bother to add it to your vocabulary at all, and certainly not your workaday vocabulary.

Comment: Dare I suggest that the question itself is either cruritractive or buccalingual?

Comment: I'm a great fan of Blackadder, and was glad to see Rowan Atkinson still on form at the Olympic opening ceremony, but realistically I think this one is Too Localised. Whatever - have +1 for publicising one of our current greats, @Yoichi! I must also admit that even though I'm as familiar with *contrafibularities* as I am with *supercalifragilisticexpialidocious*, I never realised what reviewers-choice.com says is "obvious" - *from **contra**, against, + **fibula**, the smaller of the two bones in the lower leg. Means '**pulling one's leg**,'*

Comment: I’m simply asking this question because ‘contrafibularities’ was used by a respectful user of EL&U and dedicated to a sincere user of the site, and I didn’t know its meaning. If you think this question ‘cruritractive and buccalingual,’ both of which I’m not sophisticated enough to know, you’d better to cast that word to the user whom I respect and who happened to use this word. I don’t find both ‘cruritractive’ and ‘buccalingual’ in any of Cambridge, Oxford, and Merriam-Webster English dictionary.

Comment: Continued to the above: But curiously enough, Readers English Japanese Dictionary published by a Japanese (not British, or American) publisher registers ‘buccolingual’ as meaning ‘loquacity,’ not ‘buccalingual,’ though I trust you spelt right.’

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: I think *cruritractive* and *buccalingual* are a different kind of "non-word" than *contrafibularities* and *cromulent*. The second two are actually known to quite a lot of culturally-aware people - who sometimes repeat them *partly or purely to advertise their cultural credentials*. Personally, I thoroughly approve of this, providing ***I*** know the words too - it helps remind us how much common culture we share.

Comment: @YoichiOishi  My abject apologies if I seemed to mock you; I intended quite the opposite. Observing your very polished use of the language, and your Reputation, which are both at odds with your modesty, I wondered if perhaps you were perhaps writing seriously but somewhat *tongue-in-cheek* and *pulling **our** legs*; so I manufactured those two silly Latinate neologisms to express my admiration and appreciation of your wit.

Comment: Are you aware that urbandictionary, like The Onion, is not exactly to be used as a reliable source for... well, anything?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd never encountered *contrafibularities* (I don't like *Blackadder*). But I learned *cromulent* through frequenting a Cardinals baseball site, where it is in frequent use with no ulterior sense of playfulness; and I think it's a real addition to the language. I do *not* claim that for my two nonce-words; but they have exactly the same origin in frivolity.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: Notwithstanding many other comments, I think if you can manage to "validly" introduce *contrafibularities* into a conversation with most Brits (and some Americans) over 40, they'll think you have an astonishingly good grasp of idiomatic usage. But note that using it "validly" probably means *in a context where you might reasonably expect your audience to recognise the reference*. Using words you don't expect your audience to understand is usually fairly pointless.

Comment: @Jeff: The Urban Dictionary has some uses, I've used it to research the origin of slang terms here on EL&U. For example, the earliest use of the internet abbreviation [FTW](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50404/origin-of-the-phrase-for-the-win) I found is on UD, giving a gaming origin, which agrees with later sources.

Comment: ＠StoneyB. For me to whom English is after all foreign language, it’s always a hard task to distinguish a jocular from a serious remark. It causes great inconvenience and embarrassment in either case of taking serious statement for joke, and joke for serious statement, and I admit I've made many mistakes in reading the meaning between lines up to date. My apology for my naivety of taking your witty joke for serious suggestion.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason you haven’t found it in a dictionary is that it doesn’t exist, as a word.
As a popular culture reference, it relates to the episode of 'Blackadder' where the title character decides that the best way to annoy a man who claims to have recorded every word in the language is to use words that he can’t have recorded, because Blackadder has made them up.

(I would have thought that something that can *only* be found in urbandictionary is immediately suspect to the point of incredibility, but perhaps I’m unduly cynical.)

Comment: "a man"??  Dr. Samuel Johnson ffs!

Answer (score 13):

This word will only be known to some fans of the BBC television program *[Blackadder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackadder)*. Other people will give you blank looks.

Comment: [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOSYiT2iG08) is the skit on YouTube, the word is spoken at 1:22

Comment: It's a joke word. As ΜετάEd said, very few native speakers will know the word. First time I've read it. Don't use it in normal conversation.