# Why are "hard water" and "soft water" so called?

Tags: etymology

I can't think of anything else to say. All I can find via Google is that it's because it's harder to create lather with hard water, but that doesn't seem very convincing to me.

Comment: Good question. If it’s called *hard water* because it’s hard to get a lather up, shouldn’t its antonym then be called *easy water*?  There must be more to it than that. As a kid, I used to think  was because hard water left a hard mineral residue, whereas soft water would dry into a soft, smooth ring. But you really don’t notice it that much from just one drying, only with many, many, many dryings.

Comment: [This](http://www.problemwater.com/h_hardness.html) has a “why” to it, but when you boil it all down, the residue it leaves is not all that much different from the rest of them, really.  More from [Cecil](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2143/whats-the-difference-between-hard-water-and-soft-water) & [Harwich](http://www.harwichwater.com/community/water-facts/hard-water-soft-water.html).

Comment: The [very first sentence on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_water) says `Hard water is water that has high mineral content (in contrast with "soft water").`...

Comment: @Izkata That completely misses the point. The question is not one of *what* but of *why*.

Comment: @tchrist "Why is hard water called 'hard water'?"  "Because it has more minerals in it than soft water.".  It completely answers "why is it called ___?" (with the exception of threshold, as mentioned in AndrewLeach's answer), and it isn't related to lather as mentioned in the question.  That's a side-effect of there being more minerals in the water.

Comment: This is the effect of Calcification from hard water from Mother Shiptons Cave near me in Yorkshire. http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/02/83/4c/6a/the-main-attraction.jpg

Comment: @Izkata: Your point would make sense if it were called ***mineral** water*, rather than ***hard** water*. Besides which, sodium carbonate is also a "mineral" - and by most definitions it's a "solid", meaning it's "hard". But if you add more of that, you get soft water. So your *"**because** it has more minerals in it than soft water"* doesn't really "explain" anything - and as tchrist says, I'm not asking *what is it?*, I'm asking *why* it's called hard/soft.

Comment: @FumbleFingers `From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
  (Redirected from Soft water) Water softening is the removal of calcium, magnesium, and certain other metal cations in hard water. The resulting soft water is more compatible with soap and extends the lifetime of plumbing. Water softening is usually achieved using ion-exchange resins.` - Okay, so not strictly minerals - the more metallic ones are exchanged for others.  Still, this question is easily answerable on Wikipedia, and IIRC this site still has General Reference, doesn't it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you're looking for the _origin_ of the usage, the question should say so.

Comment: @Izkata: I asked what I wanted to know, which is ***why***. If I'd asked for the origin of [contrafibularities](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79474/), say, it might be considered sufficient to say it came from Blackadder. Whereas asking *why* would hopefully elicit the additional information *from **contra**, against, + **fibula**, the smaller of the two bones in the lower leg. Means '**pulling one's leg**'*.

Comment: Anyway, mineral water is a soft drink.

Comment: @Edwin: Not sure about Americans, but most Brits wouldn't call mineral water a "soft drink" even if it was carbonated. We usually assume soft drink means it's carbonated *and* sweetened.

Comment: Tommy Cooper would have got away with that one. The dictionaries would support him: [AHDEL]  min·er·al  (mnr-l)
n. ...

6. minerals [(]Chiefly British[)] Mineral water.                       [Collins]:                                                          mineral (ˈmɪnərəl ˈmɪnrəl)
...
4. (Cookery) (often plural) Brit short for mineral water
5. (Cookery) Brit a soft drink [but I concede that 50 years ago 'Tizer' was _a mineral_ / _pop_ / _a soft drink_, but not _mineral water_].

Answer (score 36):

*Hard* water contains minerals that actually *harden*. Over time, they form stains and crusts on the pipes and vessels they contact.  If you look at the inside of pipes that have carried *hard* water for decades, there are thick stonelike coatings.

*Soft* water does not exhibit such behavior.

See a discussion of hard water deposits and scale [here](http://www.bae.ncsu.edu/programs/extension/publicat/wqwm/he397.html).

Comment: Or at least, not as much.  But yes, I'm 99% sure that this is the simplest and most correct answer so far..

Comment: It would be great to have a reference for it.  So we know it is not just somebody's guess (logical as it is).

Comment: @GEdgar See edit above.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reference does not claim to explain use of the word *hard*.

Comment: @GEdgar I have seen it explained on commercial sites, such as [this one](http://www.aquabion-uk.com/hard-water/#), but not more authoritative references, except obliquely.

Comment: -1 This answer posted by any noob would have been promptly shot down as a "not an answer". Where *is* the answer here? No offence, bib!

Answer (score 14):

[Hard water contains >160ppm of minerals](http://www.buzzle.com/articles/hard-water-vs-soft-water.html) (typically calcium compounds) and actually feels harder when drunk than soft water does (<160ppm). The earliest use in OED below would seem to support that origin rather than it being "hard" to form a lather.

> **14. a.** Applied to water holding in solution mineral, especially calcareous, salts, which decompose soap and render the water unfit for washing purposes.
>
> 1660   F. Brooke tr. V. Le Blanc *World Surveyed* 18 :  The water was sharp and hard, but nothing brackish.
> 1756   C. Lucas *Ess. Waters* i. 83  : Hard waters are the best for builders and plasterers.
> 1805   W. Saunders *Mineral Waters* 305 :  A very hard water, curdling soap, and possessing a large portion of selenite and earthy carbonats.
> 1849   R. T. Claridge *Cold-water Cure* (1869) 85 :  Hard water makes the skin rough, but soft water, on the contrary, renders it smooth.

Comment: Other OED entries that somewhere (usually in the citations) mention either of **hard water** or **soft water** are:
*bottom, bunny, calciphilous, charge, detergent, feel, frappé, hard, lather,
lean, lime, liquid, mixer, overrun, precipitator, quick, rather, sequester,
soap, soapless, soft, soften, stare, staring, steeper, strangle, wash,
water,* and *water sapphire*.

Comment: Wines, for example, can be called "soft". Generally the opposite of "sharp/acid". I'm not sure I've ever heard "hard" being used metaphorically in terms of the taste of anything. So I don't know what you mean by *"actually feels harder when drunk"*.

Comment: Oddly enough, Brooke's usage is from a translation of a French work, where the phrase is _L'eau en est aspre, & aucunement salée_. _Aspre_ is now obsolete but clearly seems to come from Latin _asper_ meaning _harsh_ or as Brooke wrote _sharp_. The word _hard_ seems to have been wholly invented.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This isn't necessarily related to taste, but I've heard the term *hard liquor* to refer to drinks with especially high alchohol content.

Comment: @Peter Olson: Also, [hard cheese](http://shelflifeadvice.com/content/how-do-hard-cheese-and-soft-cheese-differ) is older and thus *drier* than soft cheese. So in all these contexts, water/cheese/booze is harder when less "watery". In fact, I guess *life* is hard without water.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: How bout, [Hard Drinks](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hard+drink) and [Soft Drinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_drink)?

Comment: @KeyBrd Basher: All soft drinks are carbonated and sweetened (in the UK, at least). They're not really an "opposite" to *hard liquor* - I don't think they're even called *soft drinks* because of that juxtaposition (not like *hardcode/soft porn*, for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I reckon, they are called _hard_ and _soft_ drinks exactly for that reason; the way they taste! As a side note, its "_hardcore_".

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you have never experienced water "feeling harder" then I guess you have never lived in a hard-water area.

Comment: @Andrew: Where I live (nr. Gatwick) is classified as "hard water", but you could use the inside of my 5-year-old kettle as a shaving mirror. I spend quite a bit of time around Cardiff (soft), and Grimsby, where it's so hard my parents change their electric kettle more often than some people change their underwear. Since I drive between these (and other) places, and always fill a water bottle from the tap to drink on the journey, I probably get far more A/B taste comparisons than most. Can't say I notice much difference, except in cups of tea (which are very brand-dependent anyway).

Answer (score 7):

The reasonable possibilities would seem to include:

1. Hard water comes from the ground, which is hard, soft water from rain. (All the more reasonable when we consider times when people had less of an understanding as to why some ground-sourced water is soft).
2. It's *hard* to get up a lather in hard water. (Conversely, it's *easy*, not *soft* to do so in soft water).
3. The residue left behind by evaporating hard water, is *hard* in the physical sense.
4. Vegetables, particularly hard legumes, do not soften as quickly in *hard* water. In particularly hard water, they may not soften at all unless you use baking soda (which results in the sort of soft flavour and nutrition-free vegetables that was so beloved of a previous generation, in some parts of the world). Blanching in very hard water can even harden soft fruit and vegetables.
5. While some drinks benefit from hard water (it benefits some styles of beers, and hurts others), generally soft is preferred for tea-making. It's *hard* to make a good cup of tea with it.

Other qualities seem less likely; that it can sometimes taste nasty but the best-tasting waters are hard, that the waters of spas long considered to have health benefits are particularly hard, that it messes up modern central heating systems.

An interesting commentary on hard water from 1751, Francis Home's [An Essay on the Contents and Virtues of Dunse-Spaw](http://books.google.ie/books?id=ZnBbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA111&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SN4aUcOVM4iohAfhtYCIDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) argues:

> To be ſoft is one of the chief properties in the offices of common life. The hardneſs of water, I find, depends moſtly, if not entirely, on ſea ſalt : for water, that eaſily diſſolves ſoap, is hindered from doing it by a mixture of ſea ſalt ; even after ſoap is diſſloved, the equal ſolution is curdled by an addition of that ſalt. As the ſame effect happens betwixt ſalt of tartar and ſea ſalt, the curdling of ſoap muſt, ſtill be owing to the action of theſe two.

The interesting thing is how wrong they are! Now, they're clearly on the right mark in noting that salt of tartar and sea salt both have the hardening effect, but he's blaming sodium chloride for the hardness common to water, and not suspecting that it could be another salt again.

He defines "soft water" thus:

> The criterions of ſoft water are, that it brews well; boils peaſe without making them hard; diſſolves soap equally; and washes dirt entirely out of linnen.

As we would expect, having found he does not have a clear picture of the cause of hardness, he focuses on the effect not the cause.

It would seem from this, and other texts of the time that scaling wasn't much considered. That soft water from rain sources was used in some cooking tasks could explain this, as it would reduce the amount of scaling witnessed, but also complicate the question of which water was resonsible. This also in itself speaks to the most likely origin of the word; he was not the only person to note the effect on "peaſe", but it was well-known to cooks (and remains culinary knowledge to this day).

(Alas I cannot find references for the belief that hard water blocks "pores" in vegetables, nor the advice to soak beans in soft but cook them in hard for better colour or favour, though I'd like to as the foodie in me likes the idea of the dedication that uses both well-water and rain-water for the same item [just add some salt! Jeez!]).

In all, while I could just about credit the ground = hard possibility, it seems that the effect on vegetables is the most likely source:

Soft water makes vegetables softer on boiling and soaking than hard, and very hard water can even harden some.

Comment: The bit about vegetables not softening so much when boiled in hard water seemed so odd to me I asked my friend who's a professional chef. He tells me adding salt makes them soften *quicker*, but doesn't know if this might be caused by the salt increasing the boiling point of the water. About then we got sidetracked by the [problem of making a decent cup of tea up a mountain...](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_can't_you_make_a_cup_of_tea_on_mount_Everest)

Comment: Having cooked lentils in a city with very hard water, I can assure you that without a little soda you can cook them for a day and they will still be crunchy.

Comment: Agreeing with you, mushy peas, the squidgy lime-coloured side-dish to fish and chips in the north of England, come with a large tablet of soda to boil the dried green peas with, in the packet, to help create that mushy moosh! @AndrewLazarus

Comment: Ha ha yes @FumbleFingers I'm about 2,000 feet up and it even there takes forever for the bl%%dy  kettle to boil!

Answer (score 5):

The earliest reference I could find (not including that Brooke reference, which I think is erroneous) is 1712 in the [*The Natural History of Northamptonshire* by John Morton](http://books.google.com/books?id=NA7lS8YETggC&dq=%22Hard%20Water%22&pg=PA267#v=onepage&q=hard%20water&f=false). He says:

> The common springs that have a little, slight Tincture of *Vitriol*, which with us are usually called Hard and *harsh* Waters, are vulgarly known to be such by their not taking so speedy or so lasting a Lather with Soap; by their turning and curdling of Milk in case a smaller Quantity of Milk is infus'd upon a much larger Quantity of the Boyling Water; by their requiring a larger Quantity of Malt to make the Drink, that's brew'd with it, of equal Strength to that which is made with softer Waters; and by their not boyling Pease, and other Garden Stuff so quickly or so soft and tender, as do those of a milder Nature. A Person of a nice Palate may distinguish them by the Tast; And to one who washes with them, whose Skin is of a finer Texture, they are sensibly harsh, and leave a little Roughness on the Hands and Face.

*Harsh water* actually seems to be an earlier term for the same thing, being found as early as 1667 in [*The History of the Royal-Society of London, for the Improving of Natural Knowledge* by Thomas Sprat](http://books.google.com/books?id=gJhNAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22Harsh%20Water%22&pg=PA293#v=onepage&q=%22harsh%20water%22&f=false) (earlier if you count the *l'eau aspre*) and being the opposite of *soft water*. Perhaps *hard water* was derived from *soft water* as being more clearly its opposite.

Comment: The mention of skin, and your suggestion of *soft* as earlier makes me think of folklore around rain or dew on particular days. Suggesting that an association with the real benefits of soft water in these cases was long made, albeit mixed with less scientific claims about it being particularly good on Mayday morning, etc. Far from conclusive, though.

Answer (score 4):

There is an actual difference in the feel of hard and soft water. Soft water feels softer and flows differently from hard water.

I live in a place with very hard water. When I travel to places with soft water, I notice this difference right away when I turn on the tap.

Comment: Flows differently? You mean it has different viscosity and/or surface tension?

Comment: @tchrist: Yes. -

Comment: Like @Roger, I have lived mostly in hard water areas. Soft water feels soft and soapy, compared with hard water. My first experience of it puzzled me, because after washing my hands it felt like I could not get the soap off. Also, hard water has a kind of 'bite' to it which is lacking when drinking soft water.

Comment: 'Soft water' *does* actually feel 'softer' on your hands @tchrist. It feels somehow 'wetter' and it clings more closely to one's hands. I have experienced it in places like Cornwall, staying in remote villages where pure springs were the supply.

Answer (score 2):

The 'tough to work up a lather' sense ***is*** right, though not quite so literally. The *hardness* and *softness* refer, in this case, to the words' *scientific* senses- to how "hard", or "soft", the *surface* of the water is.

(I'm afraid this answer really is more school-level scientific explanation than erudite etymology, but here it is :-)

The conventional method -till the early part of the 20th century, at least- to determine *hardness of water* was to add a little soap/soap solution/soap oil to a water sample and work up a lather (typically by vigorously shaking a cone-shaped beaker to which a drop of soap liquid had been added. The practice continues in many school science fairs to date- presumably because it is simple and requires no fancy scientific equipment).

How easily -or not- water lathers depends on how *hard*, or *soft*, the water,or more precisely, its *surface* is. The "hardness" or "softness" of the surface of water is referred to as *Surface Tension*-this is what "holds water together" - an index of how adhesive/cohesive water molecules are to each other. For soap to dissolve, it has to first overcome the *surface tension* of water.

Surface Tension is also what enables a water-strider to walk on water ([visual demo and interesting article here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension))

If the surface tension is high, or if the surface is "hard", the soap and the water don't readily mix, which means the water doesn't lather easily, and you have water that can be termed *hard*.  On the other end of the hardness index/scale, obviously, we have *soft,* referring to how easily the soap additive breaks the surface, permeates the water, and turns into lather.

EDIT : Here's another reference link that explains the same concept in brief-http://answers.ask.com/Science/Chemistry/what_is_water_hardness

Comment: Does that imply pond skaters, for example, are able to grow bigger and fatter in hard water areas? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers:-) I found a wiki page, and have linked to that now, so both links in my answer are now updated. FYI.

Comment: The scientific way to determine temperature is to use a thermometer, but we don't have the word *hot* from "that which makes mercury expand in a tube".

Comment: @Thanks for the kinds words. I think this one is going to be a case where all we can do is add more possibilities and then arguments and counter-arguments for and against. I'm liking Xerxes idea that "soft" came first, because the idea that rain and dew water is better for skin seems to be very old, and "soft/hard" seems to have first referred to "rain/well" before people understood why some well water is also soft. So that it's related to soft skin is not unreasonable.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: Sure. I also like Andrew Leach's post. I think his interpretation is not just straight to the point, but also derives the etymology straight out of human nature, which makes it sound very plausible-"drink the water and tell if it is *hard* or *soft*."

Comment: It is literally hard to 'work up a lather' in hard water areas.

Answer (score 2):

Ever tried washing your hair in soft water? I did when I lived in a tiny Italian village whose source of water came directly from the nearby mountains. My hair never felt softer. And I'm pretty sure that clothes and linen felt softer too.

Now I live in a city centre, and my British kettle has that thick, hard greyish [limescale](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2009/aug/23/how-to-remove-limescale);  the taps have that tough residue of calcium around the spout, which is really difficult to shift, and the bathroom [radiator](http://www.pgs-online.co.uk/2012/10/plumbing/plumbing-tips/hissing-sounds-coming-from-radiators/) hisses because of deposit and sludge slowly building up.

Why is water called *hard* or *soft*? The deposit of calcium or limescale is *hard* to the touch, and a challenge to  get rid of. Whereas, *soft* water aptly describes the gentleness and kindness it has on our skin, hair and digestive systems. (Minestrone tastes better too, cooked in soft water, see Jon Hanna's answer.)

Moreover, think of [**hard liquor**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hard+liquor) versus [**soft drinks**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/soft+drink). You would never call a pop, soda or fizzy drink (BrEng) *easy*, would you?

Well, that's my theory. I have no backup to support my assertions.

Comment: Hydrochloric acid (a.k.a. 'muriatic acid') added to the water in a kettle will quickly dissolve limescale (especially when the water is heated), even when relatively dilute. (Note: the kettle needs to be rinsed afterwards, though hydrochloric acid is *corrosive* to unprotected tissue rather than being *poisonous*; it's the same acid that we all have in our stomachs.)

Comment: @ErikKowal Thanks for the tip. I've tried with vinegar, and the "anti-calcare" products in Italy but without much success.

Comment: Yes, I too have found that other products are very feeble compared with hydrochloric acid. BTW, it is also very effective for cleaning toilets and removing limescale encrustation on taps -- though be careful using it on metals. For instance, aluminium will be corroded by it. If in doubt, try it first on a small area and evaluate the effect. Use rubber gloves -- preferably made of neoprene -- to protect your hands, and quickly rinse off any splashes on skin with plenty of cold water.

Comment: I will try it out first on the shower head, the water jets in all sorts of weird directions. Thanks again, good stuff to know.

Comment: You will be pleasantly surprised at its effectiveness. 1) You can also speed things up, if necessary, by using a sewing pin to poke through the holes and loosen the scale. 2) An old toothbrush is also useful for removing scale, though its bristles should not be exposed to undiluted acid -- they will go stiff. 3) Finally, hydrochloric acid plus hot water and a plunger is a much more effective declogger of grease-clogged drains than products containing alkaline products like sodium hydroxide. (I've tried both.) But hydrogen sulphide gas is sometimes given off by this -- be prepared to ventilate.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence, Mari-Lou. :) I am optimistic about the degrading effect of acid on the hair in your sink -- indeed, I think it is the interaction of the acid with proteins (which hair chiefly consists of) that generates the H2S. However, the first approach should be to physically clear the U-bend if it is accessible, because long hair like yours can create a significantly large plug that progressively accumulates other debris and biological films; this might otherwise require prolonged soaking with acid.

Comment: Excellent answer!  [eyes, dolphin, whale, waterdrops]

Comment: Hydrochloric acid is very effective for dissolving limescale. but use fully enclosed protective glasses when dealing with any acid or base.