# humorous word for "foot in mouth" expression?

Tags: single-word-requests

Can someone suggest a humorous scientific-sounding synonym for “foot in mouth”?  I mean in the spirit of *sesquipedalian* for a long word.

Comment: Can you give a sentence in which this purported word would be used? (this will give us a better idea on how it should be used)

Comment: I think perhaps you misunderstand idiomatic [*(put one's) **foot in** (one's) **mouth**)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-your-foot-in-your-mouth) (say or do something that you should not have, esp. something that embarrasses someone else).* A word like ***sesquipedalian*** is a [*(bit of a) **mouthful**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mouthful) (a word or phrase that is **difficult to pronounce** or that **has a lot of syllables**).* I'm not embarrassed that I know the word *sesquipedalian*, nor should anyone else be.

Comment: Yes, *sesquipedalian* is a perfectly fine word. It isn't humorous or "scientific-sounding". It's just not very common. I provided less serious examples in my answer, words that don't actually exist nor have ever been used (as far as I know). If that's not what you were after, please clarify.

Comment: Wot? No [contrafibularities?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79474/how-popular-is-contrafibularities-as-a-day-to-day-english-word)

Comment: Perhaps *autopodophilia*?

Comment: @jxh that would just mean you love your feet, not that you put them in your mouth. *Autopedofellatio* might work, but is likely to be misunderstood. In many different ways.

Comment: @terdon: Still, being caught worshiping your feet would be awkward.

Comment: Maybe *podal-oral insertion*?

Comment: Or *metatarsal-uvular contact*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have no clue what you’re getting at.  I do know the meaning of the idiom.  I'm not saying the word is itself embarrassing or that knowledge of it would be embarrassing.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple:

- "Greek"

  *Podostomiasis*, from the Ancient Greek [*ποδός*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%B4%CF%8C%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) (foot) and [*στόμα*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CF%84%CF%8C%CE%BC%CE%B1) (mouth).
- "Latin"

  *Pedobuccality*, from the Latin root [*ped*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pes#Latin) for foot and [*bucca*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bucca#Latin), *mouth*.

You could play with them a bit. For instance:

> This is a grave case of podostomiasis.

or

> He was known for his penchant for pedobuccality.

or

> What a pedobuccalous thing to say!

or

> Ouch, that was a positively podostomical utterance.

I make no promises, however, as to whether your interlocutors will have the slightest clue what you're saying. I also can't attest to the validity of either construct, nor do I know whether they would be considered street legal in the corridors of a Classics department. Use at your own risk.

Comment: @sumelic ah, thanks. That sounds much more natural to me, but I was afraid it was my modern Greek getting in the way. I was also thinking of words like *octopus* though which uses the *pous*. Is that one different?

Comment: Never mind. Yes, of course it is. It isn't genetive there since it's "the animal with seven feet" and not "the seven-footed animal".

Comment: I think the relevant factor is maybe that in "octopus", "pous" is on the right-hand side of the word, where inflectional suffixes are expected to occur.

Comment: @sumelic nah, I think it's just my Greek confusing me. The modern Greek word is actually *χταπόδι* (from *οχταπόδι*, presumably). And the modern Greek for *foot* is *πόδι*, so I guess I just wanted to make it sound more "ancienty" to my native's ear. In Ancient Greek it would have been *οχτοπους* and *οχτόποδους*  in the genitive. Or words to that effect.

Comment: I adore the choice of 'podostomiasis' because it sounds like a medical condition.

Answer (score 2):

> He had a sudden attack of **ospedistris** and later regretted it.

Comment: I see the *ped* portion, but can you explain how it's formed?