# Where/when did the phrase "F--k the World" originate?

Tags: phrase-origin

Where/when did the phrase "Fuck the World" originate? It is often abbreviated "F.T.W." which is also used for "For the win".

Comment: Relevant [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50404/origin-of-the-phrase-for-the-win) for the "for the win" meaning.

Comment: I'll be interested to know whether it has a discernible origin. "Fuck [something]" is quite a productive formula, and I'll be surprised if anyone can point to the very first time someone happened to stick "the world" after it. Maybe there's a particular use that happened to capture an unusual level of attention, giving it meme status.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I had first encountered **FTW** in Hunter S. Thompson's *Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas* (1971), in a quote about the Hell's Angels motorcycle gang, but I don't have the book handy to check. The [Rolling Stone](https://www.rollingstone.com/politics/news/fear-and-loathing-in-las-vegas-19711111) copy doesn't have the quote. Perhaps I am misremembering which HST work it was; he also wrote a 1966 book called [*Hell's Angels: A Strange and Terrible Saga*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/067960331X), which is more likely to contain this abbreviation. The full text of *Hell's Angels* may or may not be [online](https://toleratedindividuality.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/hells-angels-a-strange-and-terrible-saga.pdf), but this link also does not contain the quote.

However, Google books has a snippet of [The Routledge Dictionary of Modern American Slang and Unconventional English](https://books.google.com/books?id=5F-YNZRv-VMC&pg=PA405&lpg=PA405&dq=fear+and+loathing+in+las+vegas+ftw&source=bl&ots=mktZWy6KSj&sig=gZ2OBxQXQFfttryjNaKPMKuko9s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid8eDQ7K7aAhXInuAKHXh-CBk4ChDoAQgrMAE#v=onepage&q=fear%20and%20loathing%20in%20las%20vegas%20ftw&f=false), which dates the abbreviation **FTW** to 1972, definitely tying it to outlaw motorcycle gangs:

> **FTW**
>   used as a defiant stance against everything -- *f*uck *t*he *w*orld
>   *US, 1972*
>
> - Both of them were heavily and inexpertly tattooed with such epithets as "loser" and "FTW" which stands for "Fuck The World." -- John Aitken, *Conversations*, p. 8, 1978
> - "That FTW is what's on the T-shirt out there on Mits. What is it?" -- John D. MacDonald, *Free Fall in Crimson*, p. 96, 1981
> - "Fuck the World" (FTW) is their motto and arrogant attitude by which this sub-culture attains its goals and objectives. -- Paladin Press, *Inside Look at Outlaw Motorcycle Gangs*, p. 14, 1992
> - -- Bill Valentine, *Gangs and Their Tattoos*, p. x, 2000
> - He noted that Jessie had several tattoos, including one on his right arm that said "FTW" (it was noted that that stood for "Fuck the World"). -- Mara Leveritt, *Devil's Knot*, p. 76, 2002

Interestingly, right above that is the abbreviation **FTA**, which at 1962 predates **FTW** and refers to the Army. It's possible that the biker gangs extrapolated FTA into FTW.

Answer (score 0):

I first encountered "FTW" as an abbreviation for the phrase in question when it came up in Penelope Spheeris's great documentary about the Los Angeles punk rock scene, [*The Decline and Fall of Western Civilization*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjZ-iWZrDr0) (1980), in the context of a tattoo that is being inked on the arm of some band or entourage member of the group X. The explanation comes at 7:53 of the linked video. I strongly suspect that "FTW" as a short form of "For the Win" had not emerged at this date, since the implications of the latter meaning run seriously counter to the nihilism of the punk ethos.